# Adding REST to Django

Tags: python, django, apache, rest

I've got a Django application that works nicely.  I'm adding REST services.  I'm looking for some additional input on my REST strategy.

Here are some examples of things I'm wringing my hands over.

- Right now, I'm using the Django-REST API with a pile of patches.
- I'm thinking of falling back to simply writing view functions in Django that return JSON results.
- I can also see filtering the REST requests in Apache and routing them to a separate, non-Django server instance.

Please nominate one approach per answer so we can vote them up or down.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> I'm thinking of falling back to simply
>   writing view functions in Django that
>   return JSON results.

- Explicit
- Portable to other frameworks
- Doesn't require patching Django

Comment: This can get you a certain distance, but if you want to do authentication then please don't reinvent the wheel - that's how we end up with lots of insecure web apps all over the web. That's why we all love the Django auth module (we do? don't we ...). A good article with more explanation ends with ["I plead with you to follow someone else's example and not roll your own authentication scheme."](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html).

Comment: There's some really good parts to that article, but the author's assertion that API keys should be added to the URL is misguided, and un-RESTful.  That's what the WWW-Authenticate and Authorization headers are there for.  (See the comments by Mike Amundsen and Ron Wail for a fuller explanation)

Comment: Whilst I agree with the sentiment 100%, "un-RESTful" does not necessarily equate to "bad". Though clearly authorization codes in URLs are certainly not good.

Answer (score 30):

Please note that REST does not just mean JSON results. REST essentially means exposing a resource-oriented API over native but full-fledged HTTP. I am not an expert on REST, but here are a few of the things Rails is doing.

- URLs should be good, simple names for resources
- Use the right HTTP methods

  - HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE
  - Optionally with an override (form parameter '_method' will override HTTP request-method)
- Support content-type negotiation via Accept request-header

  - Optionally with an override (filename extension in the URL will override MIME-type in the Accept request-header)
  - Available content types should include XML, XHTML, HTML, JSON, YAML, and many others as appropriate

For example, to get the native HTTP support going, the server should respond to

```
GET /account/profile HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
```

as it would respond to

```
GET /account/profile.json HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

And it should respond to

```
PUT /account/profile HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

var=value
```

as it would respond to

```
POST /account/profile HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

_method=PUT&var=value
```

Comment: Note that you too are not discribing rest in its full glory. You are discribing level 2 on the Maturity Model. http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Answer (score 25):

<s>For anyone else looking for a very decent, pluggable API application for Django, make sure you checkout jespern's [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston) which is used internally at BitBucket.</s>

It's well maintained, has a great following and some cool forks which do things like add support for pagination and other authentication methods (OAuth is supported out of the box).

Updated to reflect that django-piston is no longer maintained.

Comment: Django-piston can no longer be considered "well-maintained."  Although the code was stable when it was more-or-less abandoned, it has and will become more and more out of date as django (and the community) moves on.  For one, there are a host of unresolved bug reports.  Piston is dead, long live django-tastypie and django-rest-framework. http://pydanny.com/choosing-an-api-framework-for-django.html

Answer (score 7):

[Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is also a newly emerging REST framework for Django.
It has the same mindset as pistons, and removes a lot of boilerplate coding.

Comment: Tried it and it's looking good.

Comment: Its not new anymore, and its the in-thing. Along with django-rest-framework . . . both have big followings and seem mature.

Answer (score 5):

My answer to the same question here: [Framework for Implementing REST web service in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488325/framework-for-implementing-rest-web-service-in-django/6535255#6535255)

The short version is, have a look at https://github.com/jgorset/django-respite/ a REST framework in its early days, but we use it every day on client projects.

Answer (score 4):

Scrap the Django REST api and come up with your own open source project that others can contribute to.  I would be willing to contribute.  I have some code that is based on the forms api to do REST.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm thinking of falling back to simply
>   writing view functions in Django that
>   return JSON results.

I would go with that .. 
Ali A summed it pretty well.

The main point for me is beign explicit. I would avoid using a function that automatically converts an object into json, what if the object has a reference to a user and somehow the password (even if it's hashed) go into the json snippit?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going with my own REST API framework for Django (that I'd love to get rid of if I can find a workable alternative), with a few custom views thrown in for corner cases I didn't want to deal with. It's worked out ok.

So a combination of 1 and 2; without some form of framework you'll end up writing the same boilerplate for the common cases.

I've also done a few stand-alone APIs. I like having them as stand-alone services, but the very fact that they stand alone from the rest of the code leads to them getting neglected. No technical reason; simply out-of-sight, out-of-mind.

What I'd really like to see is an approach that unifies Django forms and REST APIs, as they often share a lot of logic. Conceptually if your app exposes something in HTML it likely wants to expose it programmatically as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could take look at [django-dynamicresponse](http://github.com/funkbit/django-dynamicresponse), which is a lightweight framework for adding REST API with JSON to your Django applications.

It requires minimal changes to add API support to existing Django apps, and makes it straight-forward to build-in API from the start in new projects.

Basically, it includes middleware support for parsing JSON into request.POST, in addition to serializing the returned context to JSON or rendering a template/redirecting conditionally based on the request type.

Answer (score 1):

you could try making a generic functions that process the data (like parand mentioned) which you can call from the views that generate the web pages, as well as those that generate the json/xml/whatever

Answer (score 1):

TastyPie looks quite interesting and promising. It goes well with Django.