# backbone.js translate django server template with backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, mustache, tastypie, icanhaz.js

I am used to defining my django views with http request that send http response back with a python dictionary of data that i can iterate over and display. I am attempting to replace this with the use of backbone.js.

Currently i have a set up like so:

```
<ul id="teaching_students">

 {% for student in students.object_list %}
    <li class="selected">
      <span> {{ student.name }} </span>
    </li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and i would like to use ICanHaz.js and Mustache.js as javascript templates to fill `{{ student.name}}` on the client side.

Using tastypie so far, i have a `PersonResource` which has all the students coming back as json objects when the following url is passed.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people/?format=json
```

1. Do i need to generate an API view for this url in views.py, if so what does that look like?
2. How do i call, in backbone.js, this url and set up a collection, view and a correct route ?

My client side structure is broken down into `views/models` (i use require.js to bring them together).

I am using several plugins to help bridge the gap between backbone and tastypie (backbone-tastypie.js) but i really want to see how others have replaced traditional django template rendering with REST api's and backbone.js

EDIT: Adding Backbone model, here is the model i am using

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults : {

        },

        initialize: function( options ) {

        },

        parse : function(res) {
            // because of jsonp
            return res.data;
        }

    });

    return PersonModel;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to move from server side rendering to client side rendering? This means 
you incur additional http requests. But it's possible.

> Do i need to generate an API view for this url in views.py, if so what
>   does that look like?

Tasty pie does all the work once you've specified your `ModelResource` and `urlpattern`.
There's no need for you to have another function in your app's views.py to handle the http request-response cycle.

1. Check out the [tasty pie tutorial](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources) to learn how to hook your resource to a url.
2. Use a test REST client like the [Postman chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to see if everything's ok.

> How do i call, in backbone.js, this url and set up a collection, view
>   and a correct route ?

1. Treat the api like any other. Set up the `url` field of your model to

   `/api/people/?format=json`
2. Have your view listen to the `change` event of `PersonModel`
3. [Fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) the model.
4. Render the view using the templating engine of your choice when the data is received.

Also see [Adding REST to Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308605/adding-rest-to-django) for options on providing RESTful interfaces to django apps.

Comment: So by creating a view that listens to any change in the PersonModel, i don't have to have any explicit route defined in backbone.js? How does my application then get to this view.

Comment: The view has to register a callback to listen to the model's changes... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782704/backbone-js-tutorial for more backbone tutorials

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I will post a more specific question and the errors i get.